# jQuery .load content only shows for a second

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jQuery .load to get a div from another page. However when I click the link the other page's div only shows for a split second than it reverts back to the previous page's content.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#contact").click(function(){
     $("#boxcontainer").load("contact.html #contBox");
   });
 });
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to prevent the default behavior from happening:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#contact").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     $("#boxcontainer").load("contact.html #contBox");
   });
 });
```